# Can a BackgroundService run indefinitely in ASP .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am constructing a web service that receives data and updates it periodically. When a user pings the service, it will send specific data back to the user. In order to receive this data, I have a persistent that is created on startup and regularly receives updates, but not at periodic intervals. I have already implemented it, but I would like to add DI and make it into a service. Can this type of problem be solved with a BackgroundService or is this not recommended? Is there anything better I should use? I originally wanted to just register my connection object as a singleton, but since singletons are not initialized on startup, that does not work so well for me.

Comment: Can you give more context? Are you talking about connection between 2 services, or between client (web browser) and server (iis)?

Comment: The web service has a socket connected to a console app. The console app pushes out data and the web service stores it for any client that sends a request for that specific data.

Comment: It looks like your console app can push data to a DB. Then the web service can access DB whenever it got request from client.

Comment: I'm not asking about the console app. I cannot modify the console app as it is used for many different things. I just want to know if a background service would fit this task.

Comment: What I'm saying is you're not even sure how data should be transferred. Then you can't tell what solution is good or bad.

Comment: I know the whole thing. I've set it all up and tested it. I just want to make it into a service in line with ASP .NET instead of the current implementation I have now which is more hard coded and hacky. All I'm asking is if I can use BackgroundService for that since this connection object will be active the entire lifetime of the web service

Comment: Are you referring to an `IHostedService` when you say BackgroundService ? If it is an `IHostedService` then you shouldn't be registering it as a service to be consumed via DI. You can always consume other services within your `IHostedService` but I'm not sure why you'd also need it available from the DI container. This sounds like what you need. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Thank you @jandrew. I wasn't aware that IHostedService couldn't consume anything using DI. I was looking at BackgroundService (which implements IHostedService) because I need something that runs indefinitely to be initialized at Startup, but I have been having issues finding something like that within ASP .NET that allows for DI. Do you have any recommendations? My other thought is just a Singleton that I reference in the beginning, but I am not too fond of that approach.

Comment: @SA3709 An `IHostedService` can indeed consume services from the DI container. The docs I linked cover how to do it properly. It just involves managing scopes within your background task. `BackgroundService` is actually the base class implementing `IHostedService`, which is recommended for long running tasks as you described. I'd say you're on the right track with looking at `BackgroundService`. They are initialized at startup and you can configure tasks to run indefinitely, on a timer or even queue them. Give that section of the docs a good read and you should be good to go.

Comment: @SA3709 And if you need more advanced features for resolving services within your `BackgroundService`, I'd recommend looking at maybe using Autofac for the DI container instead of the `Microsoft.Extensions` DI container. Autofac has way more features and allows for much finer grained control.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would add an answer as so expand on my comment. From what you have described, creating a `BackgroundService` is likely the best solution for what you want to do.

ASP.NET Core provides an `IHostedService` interface that can be used to implement a background task or service, in your web app. They also provide a `BackgroundService` class that implements `IHostedService` and provides a base class for implementing long running background services. These background services are registered within the CreateWebHostBuilder method in Program.cs.

You can consume services from the dependency injection container but you will have to properly manage their scopes when using them. You can decide how to manage your `BackgroundService` classes in order to fit your needs. It does take an understanding of how to work with `Task` objects and executing, queueing, monitoring them etc. So I'd recommend giving the docs a thorough read, so you don't end up impacting performance or resource usage.

I also tend to use Autofac as my DI container rather than the built in Microsoft container, since Autofac provides more features for resolving services and managing scopes. So it's worth considering if you find yourself hitting a wall because of the built in container.

Here's the link to the docs section covering this in much more depth. I believe you can also create standalone service workers now, so that might be worth a look depending on use case.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Edit: Here's another link to a guide an example implementation for a microservice background service. It goes a little more in depth on some of the specifics.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice#implementing-ihostedservice-with-a-custom-hosted-service-class-deriving-from-the-backgroundservice-base-class